# Strange EPS to PDF translate error in MacTeX

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, mactex, epstopdf

I have an EPS file that was created with DataGraph. When this EPS is viewed with Photoshop or Preview (which converts it to PDF) it correctly shows the word "Interior":

[image: Cut from Preview]

However if I let MacTeX convert the EPS to PDF I obtain:

[image: Cut from the TeXShop pdf]

This happens for all instances of "n" (lowercase only) so words like "Interaction" become "IAteractioA", but "Nature" stays the same. Creating an EPS with the DataGraph program has given me no issues in the past and it appears to be isolated to `epstopdf` as I believe Preview uses CLI's `pstopdf`. I will likely recreate the graph, but searching has not shown me anything similar so I am curious if anyone has an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Do you have any news about the problem? It's really difficult to give sensible answers without an example.

Comment: @egreg It is very difficult to reproduce and can only be done with the mentioned program. I was mostly hoping that this would be a common enough problem that someone would have seen before and thus identifiable.

Comment: This is old, but I was wondering why you don't directly export your DataGraph document to PDF? (as I do)

Comment: @FarZin It seems to be the popular way of placing images in LaTeX for my department and collaborators. Beyond that I unfortunately do not have a good reason.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem